# Hyperledger Fabric: Peers stop syncing after sometime

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We have a hyperledger fabric network in version 2.1 and have 2 peers in each Organisation , both of the peers are anchor peers. We have specified following parameters in our pod configuration of peers

Peer 1

```
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT: "peer1.org1.example.com:7051"
CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:7052"
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP: "0.0.0.0:7051"
CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:7051"
CORE_PEER_EVENTS_ADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:7053"
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID: "Org1"
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION: "true"
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER: "false"
```

peer 2

```
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT: "peer2.org1.example.com:7051"
CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:7052"
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP: "0.0.0.0:7051"
CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:7051"
CORE_PEER_EVENTS_ADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:7053"
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID: "Org1"
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION: "true"
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER: "false"
```

We are using private data collection, So we want the data to be there in both the peers of the org. The collection policy is

```
  {
    "name": "Test_PDC",
    "policy": "OR ('Org1.member','Org2.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 1,
    "maxPeerCount": 4,
    "memberOnlyRead": true,
    "memberOnlyWrite": true,
    "blockToLive": 0,
    "endorsementPolicy": {
       "signaturePolicy": "OR('Org1.member', 'Org1.member')"
     }
  }
```

The issue is that after we install the chaincode and first few transactions we could see in the couchDBs of both the peers. But after sometime the peers don´t get syc which leads to inconsistency of data in both the peers. Please let me know if I missed any configurations

Answer (score 0):

How did you checked the inconsistency? is it by manually checking the couchDB? can you verify the inconsistency by querying the chain on different nodes

Comment: what about querying the chain? like if you run "peer chaincode query -C CHANNEL_NAME ...." in both peers do you get different results? if that is the case may be the ledger is not properly initialized or previously executed queries didn't finished properly

Comment: The problem we are facing is that after we install the chaincode and try to insert some test data, we could see the data appear in both peer´s couchDB. But when we start pushing lot of transaction then we see that some data missing in couchdb of one of the peer. My understanding is that if there are 2 peers in the org only the leader peer gets the block from the orderer and the other peer gets the block from the leader peer via gossip. But this is not working always in our case.

Comment: @GPC may I know if you find any solution to the problem as I am facing the similar issue while migrating from 1.4 to 2.2?